# What is the effect scope of "git rm" command, does it have effect on all branches or HEAD branch

Tags: git

Does `git rm <object>` has effect on all branches or the HEAD only?
From what I do understand the answer is YES since for that command to be effective it must be followed by a `commit` command, but here comes my problem.

What about `git rm --cache <object>`, since its doesn't remove the file from working directory tree but from being tracked and add the object to .gitignore

My questions :

1. Does it remove the object in all branches?
2. Does it add the object to .gitignore to be ignored in next commit of repository branches(HEAD and none HEAD) or the current branch(HEAD) only?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding several things about Git. Are you aware of the role of Git's "index" (aka "staging area", aka "cache")?

Comment: From what I know @torek; staging area is other word index and I know that if I want to remove an object that is staged, I will use -f option

Comment: (Side note: "aka" stands for "also known as", so yes, "staging area" and "cache" both mean the same as "index" here.) My question is, what do you know of the role that the index plays, in terms of creating new commits?

Comment: Index contains the modifications(either new file  or already tracked edited files added to staging area) to be commited; that's what I understand. @torek

Comment: OK, good, that's close enough: in fact, the index stores "what will go into the next commit if you make one right now". (Technically not *modifications* but rather *entire files*.) What `git rm` does is to write an index entry for the file saying "leave this file *out* of the next commit", and unless you use `--cached`, also removes the file from the work-tree. Once you make that commit, the file is completely gone from the index (whether or not it still exists in the work-tree). So `--cached` just means "do not remove from the work-tree itself".

Comment: As another side note, we can summarize tracked vs untracked files as "is or is not currently in the index". So once the file is gone from the index, it's untracked. When you check out a particular commit (whether via `git checkout <branch>` or `git checkout <commit-id>`), Git fills the index from the commit you have named. If that commit has the file, the file is now in the index, and hence is now tracked. If that commit does not have the file, so that the file is not in the index, it is now untracked. This omits one complication, though (see next comment).

Comment: When you `git checkout` some other commit, if you have uncommitted items in the index, Git tries to carry those over into the newly-checked-out commit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/git-checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok; So it --cached does not add it in .gitignore? and if it does and from what I know, object listed in .gitignore are ignore in all branches; so does that mean the file I remove with git rm --cached will be ignored even in the branch I am not working on in their next commit? @torek I also want to know if we are discussing at the right section?

Comment: Indeed, `--cached` does not touch `.gitignore` (`git rm` does nothing with this file unless you're explicitly removing `.gitignore` itself!). One important thing to know about `.gitignore` is that its contents *have no effect on files that are tracked*: in this way it's the wrong name; it's really `.git-don't-complain-about-these-files-being-untracked`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[dirn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709505/1256452) is correct, so this is a bit redundant, and there are plenty of other questions about both `git rm` and what it means for a file to be tracked or ignored, but based on comments, I think this might be a better way to explain these several items:

#### What does it mean for a file to be tracked or untracked?

The short (and not 100% accurate but close enough) answer to this is that a file is tracked if it is in the index.

#### What does `git rm` do?

The `git rm` command does two things by default:

1. It removes a file from the index—except this removal gets delayed.  For technical reasons, it writes a "to be removed" entry into the index, instead of just removing the index entry.
2. It removes a file from the work-tree.

When you add `--cached` (as in `git rm --cached file1 dir/file2`), Git only does the first step, skipping the second step.  That is, it removes (with a delayed removal) the file from the index: for each file given as an argument, it writes an entry into the index that says "when the next commit gets made, leave this file out of that commit."  That is, the file is still tracked for the moment, but as a special "so as to become deleted" rather than "generally tracked".

Note that `git rm` does not touch `.gitignore` at all, in any way—unless, of course, you run `git rm .gitignore` (in which case it adds a "to be removed" index entry and removes the work-tree file).

#### What is the index anyway?

The index has a big and very special role in merges, but ignoring that, the index mainly serves as a way for Git to stage "the next commit" one piece at a time, so that `git commit` itself is very fast.  Many other version control systems do not have an index at all, and instead construct something much like it at commit-time by scanning every file.  This takes a significant amount of time.  What Git does instead is to "pre-prepare" each commit: the index holds the next commit at all times.

This means that after you make a commit, the index matches the commit exactly.<sup>1</sup>  It also means that if you now run `git checkout dev` or `git checkout feature` or `git checkout master`, Git can switch to that commit on that branch by comparing that commit's files to those in the current index.  It only needs to change out files that are *different*—or, of course, remove files that are in the current commit but not in the to-be-checked-out commit, or add new files that are not in the current commit but *are* in the to-be-checked-out commit.  So the index not only speeds up `git commit`, it also speeds up `git checkout`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This gets complicated by things like `core.eol` settings and what Git calls *smudge filters*, so let's ignore those. :-)

---

(And, of course, the index has that special role in merges.  In fact, for each file, the index has *up to four* slots, rather than just one slot.  These are called "stage numbers", and Git only ever uses at most three stage numbers per file.  Merging uses stages 1, 2, and 3, while normal operation uses only stage zero.  The index actually stores only the file *hash IDs*.  The file data—the actual contents of each file—are kept in Git's *objects*, inside the repository.)

In summary, though, the index is *what will go into the **next** commit you make*.  You `git add` and `git rm` files to update the index, and then you `git commit` to turn the index contents—the set of all tracked files—into a new commit.  Whatever is in the index, becomes what is in that commit.  Making the new commit causes the current branch to extend by one commit, so that the branch name points to the new commit you just made.

No existing commit is ever changed by any new commit.  In fact, Git *can't* change *any* object (commit, tree, file, or annotated tag), by design.  Commands that *seem* to change something, like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`, actually fake it: they make *new* commits, leaving the old ones in place, undisturbed, but then pull a stage-magician's trick, using smoke and mirrors to make it appear as though the new ones have replaced the old ones.

#### What does `.gitignore` do?  (More about untracked files)

I like to say that `.gitignore` is the wrong name for this file, because it's not really a list of files, or even glob patterns, to *ignore*.  Ignoring is more of a side effect than anything else.  The real question is what goes into *commits*, and that's determined, as we just noted, by what is in the index.  In other words, the real question is which files are tracked, and which are not tracked.

When you run `git status`—which you should do often—you get output like this (real output, but trimmed a bit for posting purposes):

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
    modified:   pack.c

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   pytest/client.py

Untracked files:
    pytest/README
```

What `git status` does (among other things) is to run *two* diffs, one from the current commit to the index—this is where it finds "changes to be committed"—and one from the index to the work-tree.  The latter finds "changes not staged for commit", such as `pytest/client.py` here, and "untracked files", such as `pytest/README` here.

We already noted that an untracked file is one that is not in the index.  So `pytest/README` is not in the index (and in fact it's not).

Now, there are also a whole bunch of `*.o` files (from the C code) and `*.pyc` files (from the Python code).  These are *also* not in the index, but `git status` is not complaining about them.  That's because they *are* mentioned, by glob pattern, in `.gitignore` files.

Right before `git status` goes to complain about untracked files, `git status` looks at the information from the `.gitignore` files.  If a file is untracked, but is also marked as ignored, `git status` suppresses its complaint.  So in that sense, files in `.gitignore` are "don't complain about".

At the same time, though, I can do `git add .` or `git add *` to add multiple files to the index.  This will update the index entry if the file is already there, or add a new entry if not.  Just before `git add` actually adds a *new* file *to* the index, though, it looks at the information taken from the `.gitignore` files.  If the file is untracked (not already in the index) *and* is marked as ignored, `git add` won't add it.  But if the file is already tracked, `git add` never goes down this particular code path, and Git updates the file.

In other words, *for an already tracked file*, an entry in `.gitignore` has no effect.  In this sense, then, files in `.gitignore` are "don't auto-add these files, but do update them if they're already added".  Note that you can use `git add -f` (or `--force`) to add a file that is listed as ignored, i.e., to force past this "don't add" instruction.

Files listed in `.gitignore` have yet a third property, though.  Normally, when Git is doing some operation that might clobber a file—such as checking out a different commit, when you have modified the (tracked) file right now but not committed the change, and the new commit to check out has a *different version* of that file—normally, in this case, Git will stop and complain that your request would overwrite a file with changes that are not stashed or committed.  But if that file is listed as ignored, Git considers the file "non-precious" or "trashable".  In this case, Git will go ahead and overwrite the file.

Those, then, are the three meanings covered by `.gitignore`: don't complain about untracked files, don't add them automatically, and feel free to trash them.  So a single file name that covers all cases would be `.git-dont-complain-about-and-dont-add-but-do-trash-these-files`, or something like that.  You can see why it's called `.gitignore` instead. :-)

#### An unavoidable flaw with `git rm --cached`

One of the main reasons to use `git rm --cached` is the common case of committing a file by mistake.

For instance, suppose that `src.tar` is a tarball file containing all the other files, and it's in an early commit and has been left in place since then.  It is full of now outdated code and should be removed.  This is no problem: you just `git rm src.tag` and commit and move on.  Nothing was using it, it was just clutter.  It's in the repository forever but nobody really cares.

On the other hand, suppose `database.sql` accidentally got committed, and it's a big and active database and has to stay in the work-tree, but was never supposed to have been committed.  In this case, you `git rm --cached database.sql`, and add `database.sql` or `*.sql` to `.gitignore` to make sure it doesn't get `git add`-ed by mistake later, and then `git commit`.  Well, that's fine for *you*: you've made a new commit in which the file no longer exists, and it's now out of the index and `git status` no longer complains about it, and so on.

But if you ever `git checkout` an *older* commit, now you're in trouble.  In the older commit, `database.sql` exists.  So Git will go to clobber the current version of the file, replacing it with the old one.  If the file is not in `.gitignore`, you'll at least get a warning—but it *is* in `.gitignore` so Git will feel free to clobber the database.

There is no perfect cure for this.  You can leave it as not-ignored, so that Git does not feel free to clobber it.  That will prevent you from checking out the older commit, though.  (This might be OK since you probably shouldn't be doing that on a live server.)  It will also let someone accidentally re-add the database.  (This might be OK as people probably should not be doing Git work on the live server.)  And, it will keep showing up in `git status`.  (People probably should not be doing Git work on the live server.  There's a theme here... :-) )

There are other, similar cases of inappropriately committed files, though, and as with all of them, there is no perfect cure for having committed them.  Just remember that when you `git checkout` a commit that *does* have the file, Git will attempt to check that out into the work-tree, and when you then go from that commit to one that *does not* have the file, Git will attempt to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions

1) The file will be removed from any branches that contains the commit in which the file was removed. Given the following:

```
$ git checkout master
$ touch <object>
$ git add <object>
$ git commit -m 'Track <object>'
$ git checkout -b A
$ git checkout -b B
$ git rm --cached <object>
$ git commit -m 'Stop tracking <object>'
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ git merge B
```

`<object>` will be untracked in `master` and `B`, but still tracked in `A`. Note that a `git stash` is needed before switching to another branch because the file, which hasn't been removed from the file system, is still tracked by that branch.

2) Git doesn't automatically add the file to your gitignore file. Git doesn't know that that's your intention. You'll have to do that yourself.

```
$ echo '<object>' >> .gitignore
```

Comment: Then @dim , what is the option --cache for ? I read that's what it done a part from removing the file from tracking.

Comment: Right. It stops tracking the file as of that revision. Any branch not containing that revision, however, will still track the file. It's just like how adding a new file doesn't automatically add that file to all branches; it only adds them to branches containing the revision that added the file.